# posting status on facebook from ios app using facebook 3.1 SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working for an iOS app and I want to integrate Facebook sdk 3.1 for posting status on facebook but I really dont have any idea how to do it. Can anybody please provide me link to easy tutorials or step by step approach for how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up your Xcode project, read the instructions on the [Facebook developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/).

You can create / open a session using `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];`

To publish to your timeline, you'll need to authorise with write permissions:

```
[[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:@[ @"publish_stream" ] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone completionHandler:^(FBSession *authSession, NSError *authError) {

    // If auth was successful, create a status update FBRequest
    if (!authError) {
        FBRequest *postRequest = [FBRequest requestForPostStatusUpdate:@"Hello, world!"];

        [postRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

             // TODO: Check for success / failure here

         }];
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 [FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:@"I've been through the storm, future, present and past.. Light as a feather, swift as a cat.. Clickety clack, clickety clack!!" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"posted");
    }];
```

Hope this helps.